# Is it possible to transfer kindle books to my iPad and how to do it?

Tags: library

I enjoyed my kindle books for 3 years, and want to transfer it to my iPad for reading when travelling. But have no idea how to move these kindle books to my iPad. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Install the Kindle app from Apple's App Store.

The app will show the same library in Amazon as the kindle does.

If you have loaded books directly then these will have to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Install Kindle application from your Apple ipad at Apple's online store. Load the books or copy onto the application and start using it.

Comment: How does this differ or improve on the other answer?